# Inserting Sub-Array into Azure's Document DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to insert a sub class (document) of "Video" into my Organization document.

However, when I try to add a record, I get "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object."

I tried to use Add and Insert, but neither worked.  I looked at the Dcoument explorer and I can see that Videos is returning "null."

I am assuming my problem is that Document DB doesn't know that Video is a list. (in my model, I have defined it as a list though)

Also, I have tried created new objects for Organization and Video.  Also, I have a class called Category, it has the exact same code (except the object is Category) and it is inserting fine.

Below is the action that I am using.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "name,description,link")] Video video)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UserSession usersession = new UserSession();

        usersession = (UserSession)Session["user"];

        Organization organization = (Organization)DocumentDBRepository<Organization>.GetItem(d => d.Id == usersession.organizationId);

        video.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        organization.Videos.Add(video);

        await DocumentDBRepository<Organization>.UpdateItemAsync(organization.Id, organization);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

    return View(video);
}
```

Comment: Side note - I have also tried ReplaceDocumentAsync (this is what the UpdateItemAsync is calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `organization.Videos` to a non-null value. Document db simply preserves what you stored. Apparently, you previously stored `null`.